# keras.utils importError in Colab cannot import name "to_categorical"

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Google's Colab to run the Deep Learning codes from the Book " Deep Learning with python" by François Chollet.
The 1st exercise is to use the mnist dataset.
I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'to_categorical' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py)
```

I copied the code to make sure there are no typos.

Colab suggests "... manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.", in case a package is missing, which doesn't seem to be the case.

I nevertheless tried:

```
!pip install keras
```

which is either incorrect or irrelevant; the error persists.

What am I doing wrong? How can I correct it?

The code causing the error is:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
```

And this is the complete program directly from the book's source code.

```
    from keras.datasets import mnist
    from keras.utils import to_categorica
    from jeras import models
    from keras import layers

    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test-labels) = mnist.load_data()

    network = models.Sequential()
    network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation="relu", input_shape=(28*28,)))
    network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

    network.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",
                loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                metrics=["accuracy"])

    train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28*28))
    train_images = train_images.astype("float32") / 255

    test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28*28))
    test_images = test_images.astype("float32") / 255

    train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
    test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

    network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)

    test_loss, test_acc = network.evaluate(test_images, test-test_labels)
    print("test_acc:", test_acc)
```

According to the book, this is "to classify grayscale images of handwritten images" and is supposedly the "Hello World" of deep learning.

Comment: Could you please share the code that is throwing the error? does `from tensorflow.keras import to_categorical` not work?

Comment: Sami, You are not completely right but to an extent.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks Mojtaba, it works! But why the error? The code is from a book published in 2017 by F. Chollet, the creator of keras; so it was most likely correct back then. So, what happened? Where do I look such changes?

Comment: First of all, I would like to acknowledge that some of the information here I will give may not be exact. The fact is that when TensorFlow was released, it was a sake library.  When Keras came, it made using the TensorFlow easier, by acting as an intermediate framework for the main library. As the time passed, Keras was redifining its functions and capabilities , sometimes very much better than its mother library. So some implementations in TensorFlow are not redifined in Keras and you have to fetch them directly from the past habits. Another example: from keras.optimizers import Adam!